# How to subscribe localstorage in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, browser, angular-local-storage

I want to communicate between parent and child tabs. I will get some data in child tab (different component then parent) and then send this data to parent. 
I think that using browser localstorage is right way. So I'm insert data to localstorage and want that parent component automatically absorb this change, get data from localstorage and close child window.

I have 2 components for parent and child windows and one service for subscribe localstorage. Problem is that parent component did not see changes because I am changing subject with "next" from child one.

service code is:

```
export class ObserveLocalStorageService {
  private storageSub= new Subject<any>();

  watchStorage(): Observable<any> {
    return this.storageSub.asObservable();
  }

  setItem(key: string, data: any) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, data);
    this.storageSub.next('changed');
  }

  removeItem(key) {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
    this.storageSub.next('changed');
  }
}
```

child component code is:

```
export class FbLoginPopupComponent implements OnInit {

     uriObject: any;

     constructor(private storageService: ObserveLocalStorageService, 
                 private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

     ngOnInit() {
       this.activatedRoute.fragment.subscribe((fragment: string) => {
         console.log('My hash fragment is here => ', fragment);

         this.uriObject = JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(fragment)
           .replace(/"/g, '\\"')
           .replace(/&/g, '","')
           .replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}');


         if (this.uriObject['access_token']) {
           this.storageService.setItem('fb_tk', true);
           this.storageService.setItem('fb_tk_is', this.uriObject['access_token']);
         } else {
           this.storageService.setItem('fb_tk_err', this.uriObject['error']);
           this.storageService.setItem('fb_tk_err_desc', this.uriObject['error_description']);
         }
     }
}
```

Finally my parent component looks like:

```
export class FacebookLoginComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private authWindow: Window;     

  constructor(private storageService: ObserveLocalStorageService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
     this.storageService.watchStorage().subscribe((data: string) => {
       console.log(data); <------------------ **problem is here. data is not loging**
     });

  launchFbLogin() {
    this.authWindow = window.open('https://www.facebook.com/v2.11/dialog/oauth?' +
      '&response_type=token' +
      '&display=popup' +
      '&client_id=123321123321123321123321' +
      '&display=popup' +
      '&redirect_uri=https://localhost:44312/auth/fb-login-popup' +
      // '&redirect_uri=https://localhost:44312/facebook-auth.html' +
      '&scope=email',null,'width=600,height=400');
  }

}
```

I can not find solution. Please help.

Thank you

Comment: Could it be that the `storageService` used in both components is not the same instance? Could you try to call the `storageService.setItem` from within the `FacebookLoginComponent` and check whether the `console.log()` is run for you?

If that is the case then you might need to check whether these components are part of the same module. [https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services) may help you in that regard

Comment: did you find any solution?